# Extract Product field for display on Test Case Search page

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am extending Kiwi TCMS for my team and trying to display the Product on the Search Test Cases page. The Product is tied to the Category field and I am not sure how to extract that field within the testcases/static/js/seach.js file.

I have traced it back to jsonrpc.js but am missing something, not sure what it is I am not seeing.

I added the Product field in the search.html file and the data is moved 1 column to the left since the array does not contain the Product field. I have tried "product" and "product_id" in the columns[] section of search.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have traced it back to jsonrpc.js but am missing something, not sure what it is I am not seeing.

JSON RPC is a communications protocol. The spec is very simple, you can find it at https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification. The `jsonRPC` function in Kiwi TCMS is a wrapper for that.

FK relationship between models are represented with a field called `..._id`. For example Category has a field `product_id`. At the same time the Product model has a reverse relationship to Category - this is something that the underlying web framework adds automatically. The field is called `Product.category`.

Checkout how to make queries here:
https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/tcms.rpc.api.html#module-tcms.rpc.api

If you have `test_case.category_id` then you can send another API request to `Product.filter` method filtering on the `category` field with the respective value.

Inside the browser console you can do something like:

```
jsonRPC('Product.filter', {category: 1630}, console.log)
```

and see the results you get.

> I added the Product field in the search.html file and the data is moved 1 column to the left since the array does not contain the Product field. I have tried "product" and "product_id" in the columns[] section of search.js.

You will have to modify the entire page (which includes search, the callback, the HTML template and the function rendering the returned data) for this to work.

It sounds like either

- you need more information shown in the search table: there isn't much space available, OTOH there is a filter per Product so if you teach users to filter by product everything they see will be related to that product so they won't need additional column for that information
- you need a more flexible mechanism for extension - it is mostly doable and possible to design pages in Kiwi TCMS to be arbitrarily extensible, however we haven't thought in this direction and we need more information about the intended use-case to figure out the underlying architecture.
- you can design an entirely separate search page, using the upstream code as your base. Then bundle that into a plugin and just install your plugin into Kiwi TCMS. That actually sounds like the best option in this case and you will have full control over that page, see https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/index.html.

Comment: The only issue since this field already exists is how to get the additional field in the list being displayed. I do not have to modify Search since it is already a field, the HTML template has added the additional column, and the rendering already displays the list for the table but I am not sure how to insert the extra field in the list to be displayed. My users are the ones that requested the field to be displayed even though they can search on the field. I do not need a more flexible mechanism for extension and a new search page does not need to be created.